# libusb equivalent of PyUSB usb.util.find_descriptor

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

PyUSB has a little utility function called `usb.util.find_descriptor` which, as the name implies, allows me to search for a description with specific criteria, for example:

```python
ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)
```

I need the same functionality in a C++ application built with libusb. However I don't see anything similar in the [libusb API specification](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/libusb_api.html). What would be the easiest way to implement the same functionality on top of libusb?

I'm on Linux, if that makes a difference. I'd however would rather not add any additional dependency, unless strictly required.

*Update*:

This is what I have so far:

```c++
  libusb_config_descriptor* config;
  int ret = libusb_get_config_descriptor(m_dev, 0 /* config_index */, &config);
  if (ret != LIBUSB_SUCCESS) {
    raise_exception(std::runtime_error, "libusb_get_config_descriptor() failed: " << usb_strerror(ret));
  }

  // Do not assume endpoint_in is 1
  const libusb_interface *interface = config->interface;
  const libusb_interface_descriptor configuration = interface->altsetting[0];
  for(int i = 0; i < configuration.bNumEndpoints; ++i) {
    const libusb_endpoint_descriptor endpoint = configuration.endpoint[i];

    if ((endpoint.bEndpointAddress & LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN) == LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN) {
      endpoint_in = endpoint.bEndpointAddress >> 8; // 3 first bytes
      log_debug("endpoint_in: " << endpoint_in); 
    }
  }
```

Iteration works this way, albeit it looks quite ugly and it's mostly non-reusable. Also, extracting the endpoint number with:

```c++
endpoint_in = endpoint.bEndpointAddress >> 8; // 3 first bytes
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: Hmm, do you see anything that allows you to iterate over all descriptors?

Comment: @Surt The interface structure has an array of descriptors (http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/structlibusb__interface.html#a072dc48e34a98aeafbd23591ffe694ce). I'm guessing it's a NULL-terminated array, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Each interface descriptor has a number of endpoint descriptors. And I was wrong, not NULL terminated, there's another field with array length.